# Setting a constant value to the initial state of a mutable string

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an application that has a list of users. When you click on a user's profile, you have the option of changing the user's account name. I want to set a constant variable to say "Editing {user}'s profile", but I don't want the constant to change when I update the useState of the user.

```
  const User = ({userName, setUserName}) => {
    const initialUserName = userName;

    return (
      <UserInputField value={userName} onChange={e=>setUserName(e.target.value)}/>
    )
  }
```

In this example, when I change the user's name, it updates the constant 'initialUserName'. Is there a way to set the constant to the initial value of {userName} that doesn't update when i call {setUserName} ?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably not with an arrow function, you should use a class component instead, such as `React.PureComponent`

Comment: The thing to realise is is that nothing is "updating" the constant: you declared and assign it as first step of your function body, and then you return from that function, so that constant _no longer exists_ because we've exited the scope in which it was declared. The next time this function gets called, a _new_ constant gets created with the same name in the same scope, and it too will be removed once the function returns.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I was hoping there was something I could do along the lines of `useMemo(()=> setInitialUserName(userName), [])`, where it sets the constant initially, but doesn't cause it to update with the updating of the userName string.

Comment: `const initialUserName = useMemo(() => userName, [])` will hold the initial value